# How to limit max number of containers running per node in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, swarm

I can set max_replicas_per_node in the docker-compose.yml file, but that limits the service, and if I'm running more than one service simultaneously, the number of containers running per node exceeds my limit.

Is there any way to set max_replicas_per_node for swarm?

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far in your `docker-compose.yml` and maybe the output of `docker stack ps <stackname>` or `docker stack services <stackname>`?

Comment: @Colin I believe the question isn't related to any specific service, but the swarm node as a whole. I assume this might be something akin to "I have a slower-running node, thus I'd like to limit how many containers it runs" or something akin to this.